# Invert Binary Tree Js Leet problem - confused about the returned variable

Tags: javascript

So there is this [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/invert-binary-tree/)
essentially, What we are doing to invert the Tree is

1. Create a new TreeNode
2. Assign root->left to ->right
3. Assign root->right to ->left

The solution is

```
function invertTree(root) {
  const queue = [root];
  while (queue.length) {
    const n = queue.pop();
    if (n != null) {
      [n.left, n.right] = [n.right, n.left];
      queue.push(n.left, n.right);
    }
  }
  return root;
};
```

However, the part I am confused about is the change was made to queue not to root.
why are we returning root at the end?
It seems like we have direct access to the reference of the initial root. I thought the root inside the queue is a copy of the root. that's the part I am confused about. why is it a reference and not a copy? is it because we have not used new Array()?

Comment: do you have some data and the expected result?

Comment: Because it's the same root. All the changes made (via queue) are to the nodes of the original tree. Referencing objects is by using pointers so if you change it one place, all the other places pointing to the object will get the updated value, since it's the same object. This is different than numbers and strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the problem states, you must return the root. But before that, you have to invert it.

The logic is to keep an array named `queue` that stores **the next `TreeNode` to be inverted** and it does that iteratively inside a while-loop.

Firstly, the algorithm starts with the queue filled with the root, so `const queue = [root]`.

Then, it gets the last element of the queue (with `.pop()`), and if it's not a null node, call it `n` and inverse its left and right branches by doing: `[n.left, n.right] = [n.right, n.left]`. This is the moment where we make changes to the **root**.

By popping it from the `queue`, we have direct access to the reference of the initial `root` object, and whichever changes we do to their nodes affect it.

---

Later, the algorithm pushes to the `queue` the left and right nodes from `root` to be inverted. It makes the loop run again performing the same logic in each branch. Eventually, it always points to a node that references `root`, which explains why it changes indirectly.

It stops running when the queue length is 0, which is when the queue doesn't get nodes pushed anymore meaning the tree was inverted successfully.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely, the tree is being inverted in your `while` loop and the queue is just working as a supporting data structure … that's why you are returning the root after the tree is inverted.